Flutter webView: how to set domain for loadHtmlString?
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key">
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
 
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadHtmlString(html);
WebViewWidget(controller: controller);

Error:
ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key.

For the loadHtmlString(), suppose the domain is not set. Is there a way to set domain?

loadHtmlString() function takes another argument called baseUrl.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
